# is_category not fetching data inside a loop with custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

```html
<div class="row sub_content">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="dividerHeading">
            <h4><span>Services, that vitsol provide you</span></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php

         $args = array(

                       'post_type' => 'topvitsolservice',
                       'posts_per_page' => 3
         );

         $vitsol_posts = new WP_Query($args);
         if($vitsol_posts->have_posts() ): while($vitsol_posts-> have_posts() ): $vitsol_posts->the_post();

    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="serviceBox_4">
            <div class="service-icon">
              <?php
                        if(is_category('web-designing')){
                            // Some Icon
                            echo '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i>';

                        } else if(is_category('mobile-apps-development')) {
                            // Another Icon
                            echo '<i class="fa fa-icon"></i>';
                        } else {
                           echo '<i class="fa fa-somefallback"></i>';
                        }

              ?>
                <!--<i class="fa fa-signal"></i>-->
            </div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3><?php the_title();  ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt();  ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="read">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Read info<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php

endwhile;
endif;

?>
</div>
```

Hi. I am using custom post type to fetch the data in the home page and I also want icon with is_category but it does not work custom post type work properly but the icon inside the loop with is_category is not showing any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure your custom post type is using the default WordPress categories then you will be able to use `has_category`

```
if( has_category( 'web-designing' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Categories are one of the built-in taxonomies in WordPress, but they only appear in posts by default. Your Custom Post Type might have it's own taxonomy in which case the function you are looking for is `has_term` as per the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) you can use this to check if the current post has any of given terms within a custom taxonom. e.g. the `product_cat` taxonomy in the below example.

```
if( has_term( 'web-designing', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```